# ConstraintLayout by Code - Set Constraint too soon

Tags: android, kotlin, constraint-layout-chains

Good day,

I need to show a list of fidelity cards, one on the others with a small border margin, and while clicking on it, it reveal it completely while sliding.

In a fragment, I use a `ConstraintLayout` somewhere in the screen that I populate by code. 
I add all child's (total known after WS called) into the ConstraintLayout, then I am using `ConstraintSet` to set the initial constraints.

But at the initial fragment creation, I have found out that **I must apply a TimeOut** between the `ConstraintLayout` population and creating the `Constraints` (disgusting, right?)

adding each card...

```
val card = FrequencyCardView()
fid_card_container.addView(card as View)
listCard.add(card)
```

Then create the constraints:

```
val set = ConstraintSet()
val containerId = fid_card_container.id
set.clone(fid_card_container)

listCard.forEachIndexed { index, card ->
    val marginTop = when (index) {
        0 -> 0
        else -> (listCard[index -1] as ViewGroup).height / 4
    }

    val rootId = if (index == 0) containerId else (index - 1)

    set.connect(card.getId(), TOP, rootId, TOP, marginTop)
    set.connect(card.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, containerId, ConstraintSet.START, 0)
    set.connect(card.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, containerId, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
    card.setOpen(false)
}

// Apply the changes
set.applyTo(fid_card_container)
```

Any idea, why I need to apply any timeout between adding the Childs into the ConstraintLayout and then add the Constraints?

Any better solution, that this ugly TimeOut?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way.

It seems that the constraints creation must be ensured to be done on the UI Thread. This is why it does work with the `timeout`.

So, I have changed the `timeout` call by the Anko call:

```
doAsync {
  uiThread {
    resetCardLayout()
  }
}
```